# How can I sort an array of objects by coordinate position and color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is an array of objects (figures on the diagram) that have a position and color. And need to get from top to bottom (by Y) a new array
sorted by color. If in words
`{blueF, yellowF, whiteF, yellowF, YellowF, blueF, blackF}`
and after: `{blueF, blueF, yellowF, yellowF, YellowF, whiteF, blackF}`
And I was tormented trying `sort` with `reduce`. But I realized that I needed two functions. One that will return an array of the position of the top color. And I will sort the second one.
In other words, I understood it. But there are no ideas on how to release it yet

```js
const Nodes = [{
    type: "triangle",
    position: {
      x: 10,
      y: 15
    },
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    type: "square",
    position: {
      x: 20,
      y: 55
    },
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    type: "square",
    position: {
      x: 30,
      y: 25
    },
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    type: "triangle",
    position: {
      x: 40,
      y: 45
    },
    color: "yellow"
  },
  {
    type: "circle",
    position: {
      x: 10,
      y: 55
    },
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    type: "circle",
    position: {
      x: 20,
      y: 35
    },
    color: "green"
  }
];
console.log(Nodes.sort((a, b) => (a.position.y > b.position.y ? 1 : -1)));
```

Comment: How do you determine which color is greater than another? Do you want the list sorted such that if two items had different color and different position you would sort by position or would the color be the more important thing to sort by? What does the F in `yellowF` mean?

Comment: It is so unclear. Please be clear about what exactly do you want

Comment: @BenStephens F - it is just some figure. What I want is to find the first representative of the color on the Y-axis and fill it. After that, other representatives of this color will no longer be taken into account. As a result, we will get an array of color representatives and use it to sort my array. (Added img)

Comment: So you want to sort them by color and if the color is the same, you sort by the position

Comment: @MrCodingB Not. It turns out that both by coordinates and by color. First I have to get the array in their order from top to bottom. And then using it to sort the original array. (Updated picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I got what you are trying to do now:

This would by my Idea:

```js
const colors = [];

// This will push the colors into the array according to their order (in the y direction)
Nodes
    .sort((a, b) => a.position.y - b.position.y)
    .forEach(n => !colors.includes(n.color) && colors.push(n.color));


// This will sort all the nodes by their color and then their position
Nodes.sort((a, b) => {
    let iA = colors.findIndex(c => c === a.color);
    let iB = colors.findIndex(c => c === b.color);

    return iA === iB ? a.position.y - b.position.y : iA - iB;
});
```

This will first sort all Nodes by their positions so that it can then get the order in which the colors appear (from top to bottom). Afterwards it will sort all Nodes by their color and position.

Comment: Here, the function that compares by color is the second function I wanted to do. And I have a problem with the first one. Which should create an array of colors like in your example const colors = ["blue", "yellow", "white", "black"]